# Netbeans - is it possible to see project source folders in a tree (hierarchical) view, rather then a flat view?

Tags: java, netbeans, directory, structure, package

I have some huge NetBeans projects with many packages, sub-packages, sub-sub-packages .etc, and it gets very confusing seeing all these package folders in the flat layout that NetBeans shows.. e.g. a.b.c.d.e.f.g , a.b.c.d.d.e.f.h .etc .etc

Is it possible to have a hierarchical directory (tree?) view, like in IntelliJ IDEA?

Thanks,
Jose

Answer (score 111, accepted):

In the *Projects* window just invoke the context menu by right-clicking on any empty space then click **View Java Packages as > Tree**.

Comment: How can I do this in Netbeans 7.1.2? I cannot see this option there.

Comment: @José just click on any empty space in the Projects window and you'll find that option. Tested on Netbeans 7.2.1

Comment: Thanks! They really hide that menu!

Comment: Still helpful even ~10 years later. Thanks.

Comment: in 2024 is still working !

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the source directory in command line, then use "tree" command to see the hierarchy of this project.